# Modificar "NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS"

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo una bbdd en Oracle 12 con este parámetro:

```
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,';
```

Necesitaría que quedase al revés `',.'`. La única opción que encuentro es:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

Pero esto solo lo cambia a nivel de sesión y necesitaría que la bbdd esté con este formato.

¿Podríais ayudarme? 
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> Pero esto solo lo cambia a nivel de sesión y necesitaría que la bbdd
>   esté con este formato.

Los parámetros de lenguaje, regularmente son establecidos a nivel de cliente, cuya configuración *ignora* la del servidor.
El servidor almacena los datos en formato binario (no se almacenan separadores, es decir, puntos o comas). Lectura recomendada (en inglés): [Format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-DFB23985-2943-4C6A-96DF-DF0F664CED96)

Dicho esto, puedes establecer el default de la base de datos en el archivo de parámetros de inicialización de tu instancia de Oracle.

```
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

Aunque estos son derivados del territorio, por lo que si tu base de datos es para un territorio específico, debiera quedar ya bien configurado al inicializar el mismo, por ejemplo:

```
NLS_TERRITORY = 'GUATEMALA'
```

[Lista completa de territorios y lenguajes(para oracle 10g)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/applocaledata.htm#i634811)

Finalmente, aunque hagas esto, cada cliente puede elegir sus propios parámetros de formato, por lo que nada de esto será "mandatorio", esto es parte del [Soporte para la globalización](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#g1028448) del motor de base de datos.